# Automatically generating last_login and date_joined values for AuthUser

Tags: django

I am using Django's native AuthUser table to store user information at the time of registration. My AuthUser table looks like below

```
class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.IntegerField()
    is_active = models.IntegerField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

I am saving the data returned from the form like the way below. As you can see I am manually adding the value for date_joined. Is it possible to automatically generate the values for date_joined and last_login without manual intervention?

```
if(request.method == 'POST'):

  form = SignupForm(request.POST)
  if(form.is_valid()):
     firstname = request.POST['firstname']
     lastname = request.POST['lastname']
     email = request.POST['email']
     password = request.POST['password']
     confirmpassword = request.POST['password2']
     country = request.POST.get('country','None')
     UserObj = AuthUser()
     UserObj.first_name = firstname
     UserObj.last_name= lastname
     UserObj.email= email
     UserObj.password = password
     UserObj.is_superuser=True
     UserObj.is_staff=True
     UserObj.is_active= True
     UserObj.date_joined= datetime.datetime.now()
     id = UserObj.save()
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#datefield

Answer (score 1):

DateTimeFields have an [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) parameter

```
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored. If you want to be able to modify this field, set default=timezone.now (from django.utils.timezone.now()) instead of auto_now_add=True.

Last login is a little bit harder since you need to determine when a user has actually logged in, this one will require manual intervention. Django appears to do this in its [login view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L55) by sending the [`update_last_login`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L17) signal

```
def update_last_login(sender, user, **kwargs):
    """
    A signal receiver which updates the last_login date for
    the user logging in.
    """
    user.last_login = timezone.now()
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
user_logged_in.connect(update_last_login)
```